# Showing a point $\bar{x}$ is an extreme point in the polyhedron

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

given such $\bar{x}=(0,0,2,0,0)^T$,
and polyhedron:
$$
    \begin{pmatrix} 
    1&0&-2&0&3\\
1&2&1&-3&0
   \end{pmatrix} x
= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
 -4  &\\ 2
   \end{pmatrix}
$$

What should I do to show that $\bar{x}$ is an extreme point of the polyhedron?

Comment: It's not, if I'm interpreting this correctly. The solution to this equation is a non-trivial affine subspace of $\Bbb{R}^5$, which has no extreme points. Is there something missing from the question?

Comment: @TheoBendit I'm very sorry that there's a typo here, I've corrected it, please check it again.

Comment: This still doesn't change my comment. Matrix equations of the form $Ax = b$ with at least one solution produce affine subspaces (points, lines, planes, higher-dimensional equivalents). The only affine subspaces that have extreme points are the zero-dimensional affine subspaces: points. Clearly $\bar{x}$ is a solution, so the solution is non-empty. Using the rank-nullity theorem, it must have dimension at least $3$, so it's not a single point. No matter how you play with the numbers and their signs, $\hat{x}$ cannot be an extreme point of this convex set.

Comment: Show that it is a Basic Feasible Solution [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_feasible_solution#:~:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20linear,there%20exists%20an%20optimal%20BFS.]